# How to resolve firebase deploy Parsing error: Cannot read file

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried firebase deploy functions first time today.

When I command **$ firebase deploy** in the terminal, **Parsing error** occurred like below.

I found **tsconfig.json file path** is strange.

Functions directory is duplicated.

But I can't find the way to collect the problem.

```
...
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .

/Users/mies/FirebaseProjects/{MyProject}/functions/.eslintrc.js
  0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read file '/users/mies/firebaseprojects/{MyProject}/functions/functions/tsconfig.json'

/Users/mies/FirebaseProjects/{MyProject}/functions/src/index.ts
  0:0  error  Parsing error: Cannot read file '/users/mies/firebaseprojects/{MyProject}/functions/functions/tsconfig.json'

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)


Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1
```

Current **project structure** is like below.

```
{MyProject}
 +- functions/
      +- node_modules/
      +- src/
          +- index.ts
      +- .eslintrc.js
      +- .gitignore
      +- package-lock.json
      +- package.json
      +- {serviceAccount}.json
      +- tsconfig.dev.json
      +- tsconfig.json
 +- .firebaserc
 +- .gitignore
 +- firebase.json
 +- firebase.indexes.json
 +- firebase.rules
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["./functions/tsconfig.json", "./functions/tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
  },
};
```

How can I fix the root **/functions/functions** to just **/functions** ?

Before this, is the correct reason for the error occred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parserOptions.project` paths are incorrect. Try changing them to:

```
parserOptions: {
  // No './functions/'
  project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
  sourceType: "module",
},
```

Checkout [ESLint's documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#using-configuration-files) for more information about `parserOptions`.

Comment: Thank u for your answers. I changed them, then index.ts file has error: 'Parsing error: Cannot read file '/users/mies/firebaseprojects/{MyProject}/tsconfig.json'.'

Comment: @debug_ing that's strange. I have same `.eslintrc.js` as you. Can you try adding `tsConfigRootDir: __dirname` to `parserOptions`? Also what your working directory in terminal when running `firebase deploy` just to check?

Comment: My working directory is `functions` under MyProject. Regardless of the `index.ts` file's error. `$ firebase deploy` worked!. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by the following workaround,

There was issue in the `parserOptions.project` paths. Change them to the following code:

```
parserOptions: {
    project: path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.eslint.json"),
    sourceType: "module",
},
```

For more info, you can check out this [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1170).